# Why is my serviceColletion not instantiated/null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In TFM net 5.0 i have a console app that has the setup as below code:

- I dont understand why i get exception "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'services')'" when running the app.
- Why does the exception refer to "services"?
- Why cant i add AddOtions(): to serviceCollection?

```
namespace funkyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot configuration;
        private static IServiceCollection serviceCollection;


        public static void Main()
        {
             ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            MainAsync(log).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
           //....business logic is here
        }
       static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection       serviceColletion)
        {
            serviceColletion.AddOptions();


            var serviceBuilder = serviceColletion.BuildServiceProvider();


            configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", false)
                .Build();

            var section = configuration.GetSection("Values");
            serviceColletion.AddMemoryCache();
           ....
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning anything to the `serviceCollection` field? How can it ever be anything but `null` if you never assign anything to it?

Comment: I dont understand, can you elaborate? I though it was instansiated as empty (reserved space in memory?) in the "private static IServiceCollection serviceCollection;".  And i would assign it something when trying to AddOptions?

Comment: @John Do I need to new-Up a serviceColletion?

Comment: in c# defining a variable doesn't instatiate it, so, yes, you need to assign **new()** value to instatiate it

Comment: @J.Salas How/Where in the code should I new-it-Up do this?

Comment: serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection(); at start of main... I'm not getting into the complexities of dependenci injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the service collection first. For example in the field initializer:

```cs
 private static IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
```

Also there are some other issues with your code:

- Probably you want to store result of `serviceColletion.BuildServiceProvider();` in a field (or maybe even the "root" service or even not storing anything - just using the build "root" service), not the collection itself (note that calling `BuildServiceProvider` multiple time is highly discouraged)
- You are adding services to the collection after building the provider - so they will not be present in the build one.

Comment: My hero of the day :) So this means, it reserves space in memory and then instantiates that memory space with a new "empty" serviceColletion?

Comment: @otk in the nutshell - yes. But I highly recommend going through some C# tutorials (for example [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/), though they can be cumbersome in some parts).